# mysql compare 3 columns order on overall

Tags: mysql

I have a game that a user can save there name and score in a database.

Columns

Name, Tries, Percentage correct, Time taken, Image set

3 of these columns are based on a score

Tries, Percentage correct, Time taken,

Currently I have the table display time ascending.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Score ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 5";
```

Is there away to compare the scores

This is an example of 2 scores

**1st row:** 46, 52%, 02:36
**2nd row:** 38, 63%, 02:47

Is there away that i can compare on average which of those should be top based on all 3 scores.

Row one had more tries and less percentage correct but faster time.
Row two had less tries and higher percentage correct but slower time.

In a theory tries: ASC, percent: DESC, time Asc

If I change the Order by to:

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM Score ORDER BY 'time ASC', 'tries ASC', 'percent
>   DESC' LIMIT 5";

Will it mess the rows up or will it display them in an order based on all 3

**This image is using time ASC**
[image: This is using time ASC]

The minimum amount of tries is 12 which will be 100%

Some how I need to compare Tries with Time

**Can I divide time / tries and then order by result**

Is the right?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Score ORDER BY time / tries ASC  LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: Can you supply a concrete formula or algorithm to rank them based on those three columns? Conditional ordering is possible if we understand exactly the conditions on which to order.  Supplying multiple columns in the `ORDER BY` as you propose would do the ordering across all rows for each component, not combine the components per row.

Comment: Also, what are the columns' data types? Please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE Score`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to divide 2 columns then order that result use

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Score ORDER BY time / tries ASC  LIMIT 18446744073709551615";
```

Then if you wish you can display that result in your table

**For example**

```
<td>".round($data[4] / $data[2],2)." Seconds</td>
```

/ will divide time by tries and then wrap with round() to round down the result.

In this case I would recommend round(??? ,2) which will output something like 3.53 Seconds

If you want an average score then use **time + tries - percent**

Lowset possible tries = 12
Time could be still high even with 12 tries
getting 12 tries will give 100% that is a high value so its best to minus that.

12 tries + 1m 30s - 100%

12 tries + 10h 30m 30s - 100%

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

```
"Is there away that i can compare on average which of those should be top based on all 3 scores?"
```

Yes.  But first you have to figure out what the method is.  Then you can implement it in a query.

Second, your query as written is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Score
ORDER BY 'time ASC', 'tries ASC', 'percent DESC'
LIMIT 5;
```

This will do nothing, because it is ordering by three constants.  Drop the single quotes, and only use them for string constants:

```
SELECT *
FROM Score
ORDER BY time ASC, tries ASC, percent DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

In practice, this would be very much like:

```
ORDER BY time ASC
```

unless a lot of people have exactly the same time on two rows, the additional ordering criteria will not be used.